# how to use FormsAuthentication to connect to SharePoint Lists service to fetch all the Lists

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint server which uses Forms Authentication.
Now i want to connect to that server to fetch all the List via Lists Webservice.

i am able to connect to the SharePoint server which uses Windows Authentication, but i am not able to do it with the FormsAuthentication.

Can you please help me to figure that out.

```
 public static Lists CreateSharepointService(string sharepointHost)
    {
        Lists wssSrvc = new Lists();
        if (sharepointHost.EndsWith("/"))
            wssSrvc.Url = sharepointHost + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        else
            wssSrvc.Url = sharepointHost + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

        return wssSrvc;
    }

    public static Lists CreateSharepointService(string sharepointHost, string sharepointUsername, string sharepointPassword, string sharepointDomain)
    {
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(sharepointUsername, sharepointPassword, sharepointDomain);
        Lists wssSrvc = CreateSharepointService(sharepointHost);
        wssSrvc.Credentials = credential;


        return wssSrvc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a Service Reference or create a proxy class using wsdl.exe and use the code below to get all lists from a certain sharepoint site:

```
XmlNode ndLists = listService.GetListCollection();
```

Let me know if you are having errors calling the `GetListCollection()` method. As long as you are able to pass the correct credentials this should work. :)